# What does "partial record" mean in the statement from GNU Parallel tutorial?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

In this [tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) this statement is asserted:

> One of the 4 instances got a single record, 2 instances got 2 full records each, and one instance got 1 full and 1 partial record.

But just before that statement, this seemingly conflicting statement is made:

> The size of the chunk is not exactly 1 MB because GNU
> parallel only passes full lines - never half a line, thus the
> blocksize is only 1 MB on average.

Asking because I'm seeing what seems like a partial record sent to one of the programs receiving the record which breaks the program.

So is a partial (some amount of but not the full) record/line ever sent to the receiving stream/program or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a bug in the documentation. Congrats.

It should read *block* instead of *record*.

The partial block is the last block of the input which is not 1 MB big. In the example this last "tail" block is 450 KBytes.

num1000000 is 6888896 bytes = 6 MB + 450 KBytes.

Everything is sent to the program - also the last block. You can convince yourself this is true by running:

```
cat num1000000 | wc
cat num1000000 | parallel --pipe --block 2M cat | wc
cat num1000000 | parallel --pipe --block 1M cat | wc
cat num1000000 | parallel --pipe --block 123456 cat | wc
```